# taxonomy term path using two different vocabulary

Tags: tokens, path-aliases, taxonomy-terms

I have a "destination" vocabulary and a "category" vocabulary.
Is there a way to change the taxonomy term path of the "category" terms to include the "destination" terms in front?

i.e. destination_term/category_term/term_title

I tried using tokens but I can't figure out how to add a different vocabulary in front.

UPDATE

Here's the situation:

I have a travel site with a main portal going to 4 different destination pages (all view pages), each set with a term reference from "destination" vocabulary. Then I have a content type for  Categories, set with a term reference from "category" vocabulary (restaurant, activities, etc).

I actually have two problems:

- I can't seem to have a "destination" path preceeding the "category", which I need to make blocks appear in the right place. (the only way that I found to do this is by cheating and adding a hidden destination term in my category voc. but that means I would have to copy/repeat the "category" voc. 4 times with a different hidden "destination" term in each. That doesn't make much sense now does it? I'm sure there's a better way. Anyone?
- The other problem is that except for the above part, I am able to make the paths and breadcrumbs appear the way it should (with the help of Pathauto, Taxonomy Menu & Taxonomy Menu Trails modules), but when I get to the actual content, there's nothing in the breadcrumbs anymore (the url path shows up ok though)! Any suggestions?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So these aren't terms that have a parent-child relationship?  They're entirely different vocabularies?

Comment: correct. That's my challenge.

Comment: So how do you determine which 'destination' term appears as the parent of which category term?  Are they linked to each other in any way through a reference or anything?

Comment: I have a content type with a term reference field for destination and another one for category. So when I create my content type, I have to chose a destination, along with at least one term from the category.

Comment: Aaaah, well that really helps!  Greg's answer below is the way to go!!

Answer (score 1):

For your content type, you could set a content path pattern (admin/config/search/path/patterns) that looked something like this:

[node:field_destination]/[node:field_category]/[node:title]

This would put the destination term in front of the category term for your content nodes.  However, there is no good way for you to put the destination term in the path to the category vocabulary, because there might be zero, one or many content type nodes for any given category, and you have no good way to relate these two terms.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Perhaps I should have done things differently then? {I'll add more information on what I did)

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are trying to accomplish.  It sounds like what you really want is a view at destination/category that shows all of your content types. As for breadcrumbs, there are a lot of ways to do that; you should open another question on that subject.

Comment: Would you know how to do this with views? I've been reading a lot of post and trying many different things but I just can't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had EXACTLY this problem since ever I started to use Drupal (2007), because we both want to have something like: -sevilla/bars -sevilla/hotels -barcelona/bars -barcelona/hotels , right?
I came here hoping to find answer, but again, as so often with Drupal: no.
However, playing around I just now happened to find an acceptable alternative myself. 
Instead of using /taxonomy1/taxonomy2/name.htm (being 1 destination and 2 category)
you can use [node:menu-link:parent]/[node:field_location_type]/[node:title]
where you do have to take care that this [menu-link:parent] corresponds with the desired destination, not always very handy but it works for me.